# How do I right justify my calculated outputs based on the longest number calculated? C++

Tags: c++, terminal, format

I am attempting to right justify a section of my output, based on the length of the longest number of numbers I'm printing. This is the output I get:

```
   //    Loan Amount :                  $ 200000.00
   //    Monthly Interest Rate :             0.01 %
   //    Number of Payments                     360
   //    Monthly Payment :              $ 1244.47
   //    Amount Paid Back               $ 448009.71
   //    Interest Paid :                $ 248009.71
```

This is the output I'm trying to recreate:

```
   //    Loan Amount :                  $ 200000.00
   //    Monthly Interest Rate :             0.01 %
   //    Number of Payments                     360
   //    Monthly Payment :              $   1244.47
   //    Amount Paid Back               $ 448009.71
   //    Interest Paid :                $ 248009.71
```

Is there a method in c++ that can right-justify my output like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Explore `std::left`, `std::right`, `std::setw` and `std::stringstream`. Alternatively, use `std::format` on C++20 capable compilers.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share your attempt.